# Search From the Plist

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, plist

I have a Plist with multiple Dictionaries in the Array.

I am unable to search from the `Plist`.When I search from the below code I can search only if enter full name of `objectForKey:@"aName"` like I need to enter Sugar..I cannot Search with sug..or s..I would have to type sugar full and If i search the Milk which is in the plist ..It will display me the first dictionary that is of Sugar and plist is shown below..
I have to search in  in order to 
**objectForKey:@"aName"**

from the plist.please check where I am getting wrong to search ...

[image: eneter image]

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
          [super viewDidLoad];

        if (!expandedSections)
        {
            expandedSections = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
        }

        NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *documentPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"p.plist"];


        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:documentPlistPath];



        valueArray = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];

        self.mySections=[valueArray copy];  
        NSLog(@"value array %@",self.mySections);


        }
        - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {


        if (tableView==self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
        {
            return [self.searchResults count];
        }
        else
        {

            return [self.mySections count];
        }

         }


        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section      
        {



        if (  !(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) )
        {
            if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section] )
            {

                return [[[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section ] allKeys] count] ;




            }
            return 1;
         } else  
            if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) 
            {
                if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section] )
                {

                    NSString *key = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:section];
                    NSArray *dataInSection = [[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section ] allKeys]   ;

                    return [dataInSection count];
                }

            }

        return 1;


        }

        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

        NSString *key = nil;
        if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView])
        {
            key = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:section];
        }
        else{
            key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
        }





        NSDictionary *dict = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        cell.textLabel.text = [dict.allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text= [dict valueForKey:[dict.allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


        return cell;
        }





        -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {
        UIView *tempView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,tableView.bounds.size.width,40)];
        tempView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

        UILabel *tempLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,3,tableView.bounds.size.width-10,40)];
        tempLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; 
        tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; //here you can change the text color of header.
        tempLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ChalkboardSE-Bold" size:13];
        tempLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
        NSString *key=nil;

        if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView])
        {
            key = [[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section]objectForKey:@"aName"];
        }
        else{

         key = [[self.mySections objectAtIndex:section]objectForKey:@"aName"];
        // return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
         }

        tempLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
        [tempView addSubview:tempLabel];


        return tempView;
        }





        - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText 
                                 scope:(NSString*)scope
        {
        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                        predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                        searchText];

        self.searchResults = [self.mySections filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

        }

        -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
        {
        UISearchBar * searchBar = [controller searchBar];
        [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
        return YES;
        }
```

Comment: "I am unable to search from the Plist" - precisely?

Comment: to me your plist looks like and array but you put it into a dictionary...

Comment: valueArray and mySection is Array

Comment: 1. open the `.plist` file in xCode, 2. press the `Cmd` + `F` and you can search in the `.plist` file immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it provides you the filtered `NSArray`, you can do anything with the result in the further.

```
NSArray *_originalArray = ...;
/*
 * EDITED : because the thread's owner has seriously no idea what it is.
 *
 * you can get the searchText's value from anywhere else of your code
 * (i.e. from UITextField, UISearchBar, and anywhere else...)
 *
 */
NSString *searchText = ...; // EDITED : this is a parameter only, it can be set freely
NSArray *_filteredArray = [originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
            NSDictionary *_dataRow = (NSDictionary *)evaluatedObject;
            return ([[[_dataRow valueForKey:@"aName"] lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound);
        }]];

NSLog (@"%@", _filteredArray);
```

Comment: ya but this above plist of multiple Dictionaries not just two...to I cannot go for `sugar` only

Comment: then set the keyword freely... it can be set to any as you can see.

Comment: u r not getting ..I have to search from the plist of key @"aName".. and key @"aName"  would be 100s in number...I don't have to search any particular one

Comment: I think you lack of some very important knowledge, and you really have no idea what I've provided for you. :( it is sad, very sad.

Comment: no man... u were searching for `sugar` only...and If the plist is of multiples dictionary of key "aName" as A,B,C,Sugar,Milk,d..... I have to search anyone ...but ur code will force me to search for only one...as I have to define  `NSString *searchText = @"sugar";` just one\

Comment: *where is your imagination, man?* you do get money for your job, I provided a part of the solution for you, and you cannot implement it in your code? what do you expect? do you expect someone else do your job instead of you? or what? **how could I tell you the** `searchText` **can be set freely? it is a parameter only!** if you can work with it, I will remove the answer immediately...

Comment: thanks for ur lesson: .. i got the answer :   
    `_filteredArray = [[valueArray valueForKey:@"aName"] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
        return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    }];`

Comment: great news. :) finally you got it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help you...

if you are using `searchBar` you should probably use its delegate methods and from that try using the `searchTableView` method..

for eg...try this

```
 -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText  {


if([searchText length] > 0)  {
    searching = YES;
    [self **searchTableView**:yourSearchBar];  ///give call to the **searchTableView** method..

    //show your search table..
}

else  {
    searching = NO;

    //set your search table hidden
}


}



-(void)searchTableView:(UISearchBar *)searchBar  {

if (searchBar == yourSearchBar)  {
    NSString *searchText = yourSearchBar.text;

    for (NSString *sTemp in yourValueArray)  {
        NSComparisonResult result = [sTemp compare:searchText options: (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

        if (result == NSOrderedSame)  {
            [self.yourTemporarySearchArray addObject:sTemp];


        }
    }

    [yourSearchTable reloadData];
}

}
```